# Socket.io php - не работают свои функции

Tags: php, socket.io

Использую этот код для работы socket.io - [github](https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io)

там изначально в файле server.php описаны функции и если их вызывать - они работают хорошо. но если написать свою - она не работает.

Выходит, что их надо еще где то прописывать? или как?

Comment: А вы свою функцию вызываете? Она просто не срабатывает, или есть ошибки?

Comment: да, я написал свою функцию и вызываю ее. ошибок нету и реакции тоже

Comment: Добавьте в свой вопрос код функции и её вызов. Без кода толком ничего не понятно

Comment: спасибо за помощь, разобрался. я тупо не перегружал сервер после описания новых функций

Comment: Так ответьте сами на свой вопрос. Или удалите его.